# jQuery DataTable with AJAX not working on IIS server in MVC project

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis, datatables

I have one MVC project, where i have a jquery datatable and i load data to it with ajax. Everything works locally, but i had put my project on an IIS server and i receive following error when i try to access page with datatable : "Error.
An error occurred while processing your request."

In console I receive the following error message: "GET http://10.222.160.17/IpAddressingProgram/Home/Admin 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Please HELP ME!

My view page:

```
    <body>
    <div class="fw-body">
  <div class="content table_click" id="content">
        <table id="theTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" style="visibility:hidden;width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr >
                    <th >ID</th>
                    <th >Line</th>
                    <th >Station</th>
                    <th >Equipment</th>
                    <th >Equipment ID</th>
                    <th >Supplier</th>
                    <th >Production Area</th>
                    <th >IP Address</th>
                    <th >IP Mask</th>
                    <th >IP Gateway</th>
                    <th >BPA</th>
                    <th >User Extt</th>
                    <th >Physical connection</th>
                    <th ">Camline</th>
                    <th >Supplier contact</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS page:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

$('#theTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "../Home/GetGata/",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
    { "data": "ID" },
    { "data": "Line" },
    { "data": "Station" },
    { "data": "Equipment" },
    { "data": "Equipment_ID" },
    { "data": "Supplier" },
    { "data": "Production_Area" },
    { "data": "IP_Address" },
    { "data": "IP_Mask" },
    { "data": "IP_Gateway" },
    { "data": "BPA" },
    { "data": "User_Extt" },
    { "data": "Physical_network_connection" },
    { "data": "Camline" },
    { "data": "Supplier_Contact" }
    ],

    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    responsive: true,
    processing: true
});
});
```

And my Controller:

```
       public ActionResult Admin()
    {
            return View();
    }
    public JsonResult GetGata()
    {
        try
        {
            using (IPAdressProgramEntities r = new IPAdressProgramEntities())  //database entities
            {
                var data = r.All().ToList();
                //ViewBag.IPTable = data;
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It means you have error in your server side. Try check your C# code.

Comment: Log the error and check the problem or share it here .. you can use Elmah for that .. or If it is not live project, make custom Error Off in web.config to see more details about issue

Comment: I just found what problem was with custom errors off. I had a line in my code commented with @*text*@. Thank you!

Comment: I doubt it is the source of your problem but the header element for "Camline" has a stray quote character in the element.  FYI